# wordpress HTTPS redline error

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, cloudflare

Help! I have added free Cloudflare SSL certification to my Wordpress website.
then I changed the site URL in the settings to HTTPS. once I was in the plugins dashboard and clicked deactivate to the (Cloudflare Flexible SSL) plugin. I couldn't open the website anymore as I entered in a loop of redirections. I deleted the website from Cloudflare then I got an error loading the page redlined HTTPS.  So I opened the files on CPanel and removed the plugin from the plugins directory and put these two lines in the `functions.php` file in the first PHP function:

define('WP_HOME','http://www.kidcitytoys.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.kidcitytoys.com');

Also I added to the wp-config file this line:

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);

But all of this didn't help. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but did you change your website address in General settings? Most of the plugins/functions hook onto that, and errors most likely would have fixed themselves.

The redlined HTTPS means the website you are trying to access is via HTTPS, however it doesn't have a valid SSL certificate.

From what I understand you don't want to use SSL anymore right? If so you can direct your HTTPS links to your HTTP website, and that way no errors should happen on client side.

Please feel free to correct me if any of this is wrong.

Comment: yes, i have changed the website address in general settings to https . also, yes I don't want to use https anymore. so how can i fix this! i did the changes i mentioned above and nothing changed

Comment: I can't access WordPress dashboard at  all to edit this.

Comment: If you can access site files via SSH or FTP, edit them via wp-config.php Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL . Once again this may fix it, no guarantees.